# Windows 7 Backup to Network Drive - Error 0x80070003, 0x80070057

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I am trying to use Windows Backup using a network drive location as my backup destination.

Some essential stats:

- The desktop is a Win7 machine and network drive is running Win Server 2012 R2.
- I have other directories on the network drive shared to the desktop; no problems accessing them.
- Everything I am doing is on an internal, local network

I am able to select my network drive fine, and my credentials are accepted, no problems.

This brings me to 'what do you want to back up?'.

**If I pick 'Let Windows choose' (which I don't want):**

1. Goes to review settings screen, then save and exit
2. Then get 'backup did not complete successfully' error
3. Details: `The system cannot find the path specified - Error code: 0x80070003`

**If I pick 'Let me choose' (which I want):**

1. Immediately get alert: `The system cannot find the path specified - Error code: 0x80070003`. I click okay
2. Screen appears like this: [image] Because there is nothing available, I click next
3. Immediately get alert: `The parameter is incorrect (0x80070057)`. I click okay, the same message immediately comes up again, I click okay. (This happens twice every time I test it)
4. Screen appears like this: [image]
5. I save and exit
6. Then get 'backup did not complete successfully' error
7. Details: `The system cannot find the path specified - Error code: 0x80070003`

Open to any/all suggestions.

Comment: "I am able to select my network drive fine,"  So you're picking a mapped drive letter as the target?  If so, then instead of doing that, navigate to the share's UNC path directly in Backup and try it again.

Comment: "you're picking a mapped drive letter as the target?" No - what I meant was that I can 1. 'save on a network...' ->  2. browse network locations ->  3. pick server -> 4. select directory -> 5. enter credentials -> 6. click okay -> 7. return back to original menu - with no errors.

I do have the path mapped as a letter on the client, but I am selecting the network directory - \\server_name\target_directory\ - directly in Backup